# Spark realtime processing with 1 or multiple jobs in one application

Tags: apache-spark

I'm curious to find out what the best practice approach is with designing spark streaming applications.

We have a number of data sources we want to ingest, clean and transform over kafka using spark streaming.

The processing is broken down into 3 steps resulting in a new topic with new structure in each topic, e.g. Raw, standardised and logical.

The question relates to the design of the spark steaming applications. I see 3 options

1. 1 streaming application per step meaning 3 running spark jobs per source
2. 1 streaming application per source meaning 1 running spark Job that reads and writes multiple topics for the same source
3. 1 streaming application for all sources and topics.

My intuition tells me that option 2 is best tradeoff as option 1 results in far too many running spark jobs and too much complexity in a single job.

However is it actually a good idea at all to have a single spark Job do more than 1 step in the pipeline at all? If the job was to stop or fail, could it be less reliable or result in data loss of some sort?

Comment: are these three steps interrelated? i.e. is it the case that step 2 is dependent on step 1? So if step 1 fails then can you still process steps 2 and 3?

Comment: Good question, the steps are dependent, I. E. The output of raw is the input to standardised, which creates the input to logical

Comment: Ok with that information I am a bit confused about the flow. Is this a correct representation of the flow of data?  "sources -> step1(raw) -> topic1 -> step2(standardized) -> topic2 -> step3(logical) -> target".  or there is more complexity involved in the flow?

Comment: streaming or structure streaming

Comment: @vatsalmevada Yes that flow is correct

Comment: @thebluephantom mostly dealing with streaming, but some sources could have a mix

Comment: @vcetinick any specific reason for using legacy DStream based streaming over Structured Streaming?

Comment: @vatsalmevada - for some sources its unstructured data that needs to be structured, so applying the transformations ends up being far simpler using DStreams at least thats my experience.  It could be naive, but my thinking was that DStreams is better for ETL and Structured Streaming is better for analytical type use cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As confirmed in the comments section the flow looks something like following:

`sources -> step1(raw) -> topic1 -> step2(standardized) -> topic2 -> step3(logical) -> target`

I would keep the entire streaming pipeline in a single application (i.e. 3rd option mentioned by you). Following are the benefits of this approach:

- No need of writing intermediate results (of Step 1 and 2) on disk (either on a Kafka topic or on files). Why involve disk IO when the entire computing can be done in memory. That is the whole
- A single application will be easy to maintain. i.e. all your transformation logic can be in a single application. Also adding a new transformation (step) in the same application would be easy as compared to spawning a new application for a new transformation (step).

**Regarding your concern of data loss:**

Not quite sure about DStream based Streaming, but for Structured Streaming, if your streaming application fails by whatever reason, Spark will reprocess the data of the most recent batch (for which the job failed) as far as your source is replayable. So there won't be data loss but there could be duplicate data. Check this link: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#fault-tolerance-semantics

For Dstream based Streaming also I believe there is a zero data loss guarantee. Check this link: https://databricks.com/blog/2015/01/15/improved-driver-fault-tolerance-and-zero-data-loss-in-spark-streaming.html

However, I don't have much hands-on experience in Dstream based model. So I wouldn't comment much on that.

**Note:** I have assumed that intermediate result of step 1 and step 2 won't be used by any other application or job other than step 2 and step 3. If you have to store the intermediate results, then we need to rethink the approach.

Comment: Seems convenient to wrap all transformational logic into a single application, but feels more brittle from a runtime time perspective as anytime a source is added/modified/updated the realtime processing is affected for everything even if the job was to fail completely it fails for everything.

Comment: I agree. That's why I mentioned the assumption that if you are using intermediate results of step1 and step2. So let's say you have separate applications for all steps and step 1 pass and step 2 fails, in that case, are you using output of step1 for analytics query or will it be useful to some other applications?